# In/With regard to are informal?

Tags: formality

```
Her Ladyship's Guide to the Queen's English by Caroline Taggart
```

suggests that all the forms in *regard* be informal [image: A]

Are you in accord with her ? I use it in my future article and wish to be formal.

Comment: I would say:  *I would like to speak to you regarding the committee meeting" ................. (but I am not a Queen)

Comment: Are you sure that you have properly grasped Taggart's point? While I personally would agree with the quoted recommendation *with regard to* and *as regards* should be avoided, that is because of triteness and verbosity rather than informality. And 'suggesting that all the forms of *regard* be informal' is not at all the same as saying that they are informal (at least at this level of  precision).

Comment: @TimLymington:  You are probably correct....I have trouble with "formality" vs "informality" or "levels of formality".......do you have a reference for formality criteria??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: my comment was addressed to Jane the OP, but most style guides will distinguish language that is appropriate in academic or business contexts from simple communication with friends.

Comment: TimLymington: Are you suggesting that "in regard" is accepted by the author ?

Comment: @Jane (please put @ before a name, so the system can alert the person about your comment): no, Taggart and I agree that *in regard to, with regard to* and *as regards* are all bad choices. But I say this is not because they are informal, but because they are what Orwell called "debased language"; empty phrases that look and sound impressive without adding anything. ('Politics and the English Language', https://www.mtholyoke.edu/acad/intrel/orwell46.htm, which I would recommend everyone writing English to reread monthly). I suspect Taggart agrees, but I cannot tell from your quote.

Answer (score 1):

When "in/with regard to" is only a swollen and unnecessary variant for "about" I would always prefer the simpler and shorter preposition "about".

I would use the expression with "regard" when a simple preposition is not enough or hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Both are formal.Example."I am writing with regard to /in regard to /with reference to..."